# Yolo5 model training fails with CUDA out of memory even with an AWS P8 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pytorch, gpu, yolov5

I am training a yolo5 on a custom dataset but I keep running out of memory for GPU as it only uses one of the 8 GPUs. How should I run it in order for it to use all of the GPUs?

YOLOv5 v4.0-83-gd2e754b torch 1.7.1 CUDA:0 (Tesla K80, 11441.1875MB)
CUDA:1 (Tesla K80, 11441.1875MB)
CUDA:2 (Tesla K80, 11441.1875MB)
CUDA:3 (Tesla K80, 11441.1875MB)
CUDA:4 (Tesla K80, 11441.1875MB)
CUDA:5 (Tesla K80, 11441.1875MB)
CUDA:6 (Tesla K80, 11441.1875MB)
CUDA:7 (Tesla K80, 11441.1875MB)

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 16.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 10.66 GiB already allocated; 2.31 MiB free; 10.72 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch

Thanks
Ganesh